# how to assess how likely it is that a candidate gets more than 50% of the total votes

Tags: probability

So far in a country are counting votes and 72.9% of the votes have been counted. Candidate A has 43.8% of the votes, candidate B has 43.54%. Assuming that there are not a significant difference between the people that they already count vs the ones left (big assumption). How likely is that candidate has more than 50% of the total votes?

PD: there are more than 6 candidates

Comment: This ancient problem (dating at least to the early 13th century CE) is known as the [Problem of Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points).  It was solved by Pascal and Fermat in 1654.  Among other things, the solution demonstrates the answer depends on the *numbers* of votes, not just their percentages; and that it requires a strong condition: the counted votes must be a random sample of all votes.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is going to depend on the total number of votes. I'm struggling a bit with your statement of "assuming [no] significant difference (big assumption)" between votes counted and still to be counted; on the one hand I think this is usually a reasonable assumption if the number of votes is sufficiently large and they are not counted in a highly systematic way. On the other hand the probability will be effectively zero is you assume that the observed voting pattern perfectly predicts the final one. I read your actual question closer to 'how big would the voting pattern have to *deviate* from its current distribution for a candidate to get 50%'.

Let's focus on candidate A because they're currently in the lead, the probabilities will only be lower for other candidates. They have 43.8% of 72.9% of the votes, so already in their pocket is roughly 31.9% of the total number of votes (not all of which are counted yet). This means that they still need at least 66.7% of the *remaining* votes to reach 50% in the end.

You could approach this question from at least two angles, though the conclusion will not be too different. First, assuming that candidate A is expected to get 43.8% of the total votes, how likely is it that they would indeed win at least 66.7% of the ones that remain and reach 50% total? Second, conditional on the number of votes already won and lost by candidate A, how likely is an actual win percentage of at least 66.7%? (I would not consider 50% in this second one because that may predict candidate A winning a *future* election but not this one; they need more votes now)

The first interpretation is closer to your original question, 'given that we assume no change in voting patterns'. The second is closer to my rephrasing, 'how likely would a still-winning voting pattern be'. The difference is a bit philosophical but so is 'probability'. The first is how we actually call elections, I guess the difference between the two is what frequentists would call a type I error? Either way, if you plot these probabilities for a few values of total votes it looks like this (left is 1, right is 2, note the y axis scale differs):

[image]

Unless your election contains less than a few hundred votes total, which from the rounding of the percentages I assume it doesn't, chances of any candidate still reaching 50% are almost nonexistent.